# ActiveMQ Messages are Enqueued but not sent to Consumer

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am working with activemq 5.13 and network of brokers configuration .
I have a queue that for a long period of time is working fine (for few days messages are Enqueued and Dequeue normally ) . After some time it seems that the consumer stops dequeuing messages from the queue.
The broker jmx shows that the consumer is still listening on queue ("ConsumerCount" : 1)  and I check the thread state is on WAITING(not blocked ).
The consumer I am using is created by spring framework.
I am using messages **without TTL** and with **producerFlowControl="false"**
The memory of the queue is increasing ("MemoryPercentUsage" : 834,)  and after a while the producer blocks.
Any Idea what could cause that kind of behavior ?

**The borker JMX info of the queue**

```
"name" : "org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=ig2-2,destinationType=Queue,destinationName=shTdrInputQueue-2",
"modelerType" : "org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.QueueView",
"MessageGroups" : "{}",
"MessageGroupType" : "cached",
"CursorFull" : true,
"CursorMemoryUsage" : 437616304,
"CursorPercentUsage" : 834,
"CacheEnabled" : false,
"Paused" : false,
"QueueSize" : 326602,
"Options" : "",
"Subscriptions" : [ "org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=ig2-2,destinationType=Queue,destinationName=shTdrInputQueue-2,endpoint=Consumer,clientId=ID_deu-via-5-tdr-1-19222-1494485771026-23_1,consumerId=ID_deu-via-5-tdr-1-19222-1494485771026-24_1_3_1" ],
"ProducerCount" : 1,
"ConsumerCount" : 1,
"AverageMessageSize" : 1340,
"MaxMessageSize" : 1520,
"MinMessageSize" : 1239,
"MemoryPercentUsage" : 834,
"MemoryLimit" : 52428800,
"EnqueueCount" : 348003987,
"DequeueCount" : 347677385,
"ForwardCount" : 0,
"DispatchCount" : 347677385,
"InFlightCount" : 0,
"ExpiredCount" : 0,
"StoreMessageSize" : 437616304,
"MemoryUsageByteCount" : 437616304,
"AverageEnqueueTime" : 0.3380297657266376,
"MaxEnqueueTime" : 3010,
"MinEnqueueTime" : 0,
"MemoryUsagePortion" : 0.0,
"AverageBlockedTime" : 0.0,
"TotalBlockedTime" : 0,
"BlockedSends" : 0,
"SlowConsumerStrategy" : null,
"DLQ" : false,
"MaxPageSize" : 200,
"UseCache" : true,
"PrioritizedMessages" : false,
"MaxAuditDepth" : 10000,
"ProducerFlowControl" : false,
"AlwaysRetroactive" : false,
"BlockedProducerWarningInterval" : 30000,
"MaxProducersToAudit" : 64,
"Name" : "shTdrInputQueue-2"
```

Comment: Were you bale to solve this problem?

Comment: The problem in my case was that another queue in the broker was full (and it took most of the broker memory) and when the broker had memory problem it started to work slow and all other queues got full as well